# How to get backref using natbib with IEEE bibliography style

Tags: natbib, ieeetran, backref

I would like to know how to go about getting the back ref "`(cited on page 1)`" text to show up in the bibliography section of my document.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,10pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{filecontents}{IEEEexample.bib}
@inBook{Wolff1962,
  Title                    = {Philosophia prima sive Ontologia},
  Author                   = {Wolff, Christian von},
  Editor                   = {Jean Ecole},
  Publisher                = {Olms},
  Address                  = {Hildesheim},
  Year                     = {1962},
  Part                     = {Abt. 2: Lateinische Schriften},
  Maintitle                = {Gesammelte Werke},
  Volume                   = {3},
  langid                   = {german}
}

@inBook{other1999,
  Title                    = {The title in english},
  Author                   = {Last, Name},
  Editor                   = {Editor Name},
  Publisher                = {Springer},
  Address                  = {New York},
  Year                     = {1999},
  Part                     = {1},
  Maintitle                = {The Maintitle},
  Volume                   = {3},
}

@techreport{Natarajan2011,
author = {Natarajan, Nagarajan and Singh-Blom, Ulf Martin and Tewari, Ambuj and Woods, John O and Dhillon, Inderjit S and Marcotte, Edward M},
file = {:Users/jwoods/Downloads/Papers/Natarajan2011.pdf:pdf},
journal = {UTCS Technical Report},
title = {{Predicting gene\textendash disease associations using multiple species data.}},
volume = {TR-11-37},
year = {2011},
type = {techreport},
keywords = {Technical Report}}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[square,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter Name}
\lipsum[1] \cite{Wolff1962}

\lipsum[2] \cite{Natarajan2011}



\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEexample.bib}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the `hyperref` package, as in your MWE, you have to load the `backref` package. Oppositely, if you in fact use `hyperref`, don't load explicitly `backref`, but add `backref` or better `pagebackref` in options passed to
`hyperref`.

Important: theses options belong to the set of options that should be provided at load time, and can't be activated later with  `\hypersetup`.

If this triggers an "option clash" for `hyperref`, remove it from the option list, but add at the beginning of your file the command `\PassOptionsToPackage{pagebackref}{hyperref}`.

This holds for the bibtex route, independently of `natbib`.
For the biblatex route, there are posts on this forum, that you w'd get by searching backref + biblatex  in your favorite search engine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  I added the package `\usepackage{backref}` but for some reason, I am not seeing the comment `(cited on page 2)` for example in the document.  I am only seeing `pages 2` (for example).  Is there additional code to add for the backref package to help show `(cited on page 2)`

Comment: For this formatting issue, please look at the section 2.3.1 or 2.3.2 of  backref's manual.

Comment: Likely you have foxed this. In the negative case, I have small package that handles this for English and for French, to be loaded after `babel` and before `hyperref`, buy also works without any of them. You can get it at https://www.dropbox.com/s/z3o3w8fkjzf4vrm/citebackref.sty